Which compatibilities are missing? (ChromeOS app development)
I released an app on the Google PlayStore, specifically for ChromeOS.
It's an training app used in some organizations.
I've been getting reports of users not being able to install the app because they're getting the red "your device isn't compatible" message replacing the install button in the PlayStore.
I have a HP ChromeBook that I tested the app on, and it works fine. I can install the app from the PlayStore without issue.
I made sure the version of ChromeOS is newer than that of the users reporting the issue.
I made sure that all the uses-feature records in the manifest have required set to false.
However, it still gives this message for some end-users.
Is there any way to see what is conflicting with the app?
Is there any way to see which requirements are missing to install the app?
